# Agile task board and customising descriptions in collapsed views

Tags: tfs

So I created a custom column for my Agile board, and assigned it an "InProgress" type for the new state. This then gives it an "in progress" description when all the stories are collapsed.

Ideally I'd like the custom state to have it's own description "ready to deploy" description when all items collapsed so I can tell between active items and items that are completed and awaiting deployment.

I am thinking it has something to do with categories but I can't find anything to point me in the right direction.
[TFS Agile task board collapsed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYvXi.png)

Thanks,
Angus.